# Decrypting files via Runtime.getRuntime().exec without Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption

My code decrypt all the encrypted files in folder, but I used Thread.sleep(). If I dont use  Thread.sleep(); program can't decrypt all files. I'm looking for better way how to decrypt all files without Thread.sleep();

I need to write conditions in code, where this code is waiting until the file is decrypted. Could you help me?

My code:

```
public static void decrypt() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    File folder = new File("c:/Users/hajdukri/Desktop/src");
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();

    String pass;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a password");
    pass = in.nextLine();

    if("pass123456".equals(pass)){
        for(File a :files){
            Thread.sleep(500);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start C:\\Users\\hajdukri\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication3\\gpg.bat");

            if (a.isFile()) {
                String fileName = a.getName();
                // get only only last index (exeption)
                int co = fileName.lastIndexOf('.')+1;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fileName); 
                sb.delete(0, co); 
                sb.toString();

                if ("gpg".equals(sb.toString())){
                    int last = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
                    StringBuilder delLast = new StringBuilder(fileName); 
                    delLast.delete(last, 4+last); 
                    delLast.toString();

                    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\hajdukri\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication3\\gpg.bat");
                    String content = "cd C:\\Users\\hajdukri\\Desktop\\src \r\ngpg --output "+ delLast +" --batch --passphrase "+"\""+pass+"\""+  " "+" --decrypt "+ fileName +"\r\nexit b/";
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
                        bw.write(content);
                        bw.close();
                    }   
                }  
            }    
        }
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Invalid password entered!");}
 }
```

I need to run Runtime.getRuntime().exec (gpg.bat) for the next files only when the  previous file is decripted.

Thank a lot.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec() returns a Process object. Use the objects waitFor() method to wait until your subprocess completes.

Comment: I used waitFor(), but the code didn't work correctly. I try to decrypt 5 files in folder, but the program decrypt only 4 sometimes only 3 files.

Comment: Add debug statemenrs to your code to see exactly where it gets stuck. If you saying sometimes it decrypts till 4 files and last one fails could be something going wrong at that time.

Comment: if I use debug (F7 in Netbeans step by steps) the program works correctly. this is longer  process like (F6 run project) and the program have a enought time to do everything. I try to debug x time, but program run correctly via debug.

Comment: In my opinion the program hasn't enough time to write to batch file 3 lines in for ciklus. but  this  is intetersting ... If I use Thread.sleep(500) the code work correctly  because before decripting files wait 500ms... but this isn't good solution. when the system  usage 70%-90% 500ms is not enough... :(

Answer (score 0):

The Runtime.exec() returns a Process object.

You must **read the output and the error streams**. If you don't, the small OS buffer will fill up and the process (cmd.exe) will hang until you do.

And since both streams are blocking, you need at least 2 threads (typically 1 thread for the error stream while the current thread read the process output). For solid control, I normally put 2 threads on the streams while my current thread waits for the process, with a timeout, and kills it if required.

If you don't have any outputs, you might get away without reading the err/out streams, but you won't see issues. Yet you must still use **Process.waitFor()** unless you intend to have a limited number running concurrently.

Also, a child process is consuming a few system descriptors. So you cannot spawn thousands without concerns...

Other consideration: HotSpot Runtime.exec is VERY VERY BAD at spawning child process when the JVM heap is really high. Let's say you have a 10 GB jvm, spawning a child exec fork will require a 10GB from the virtual memory. So, in such env, doing more than 1 exec gets really tricky. (I had to use a tiny exec daemon that has no issued forking processes to which I communicate through socket).